# How to insert data to array from array after click button

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need insert data from array contacts to array data one by one after click button. After click button insert contacts[0], after another click insert contacts[1] without contacts[0] and contacts[2...] after next click insert contacts[2]...

```
<button id="submit-btn" onclick="myFunc()">Search</button>

  const contacts = ['Chriss:23232','Sarah:345232','Bill:893246','Mary:254366',
                    'Dianne:2434356','Amy:2356546','Andreu:23546457'];


    var data = [];
    function myFunc(){
            //var res = contacts.filter(f => !data.includes(f));

        for ( let x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++ ){
            data.push(contacts[x]);
        }
    }
```

This will save whole contacts.

Comment: do you want to keep the contacts array intact or you want to remove those elements from contacts after inserting elements into data array?

Comment: keep original contacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) along with a check that  clicks are not going beyond length of array. if you don't add check than after exceeding array length it will keep adding `undefined`

You can use a global variable as index tracker and keep updating and every time you click on button and push values in your data array. But in JS world it is generally considered as an anti-pattern to use global variables.

```js
const contacts = 
['Chriss:23232','Sarah:345232','Bill:893246','Mary:254366','Dianne:2434356','Amy:2356546','Andreu:23546457'];

    var data = [];
function myFunc(){
  if(contacts &&contacts.length > 0)
  {
    data.push(contacts.shift());
    console.log(data)
  } else {
    console.log('No more contacts in your list')
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="submit-btn" onclick="myFunc()">Search</button>
```

Comment: maybe just add a fail safe mechanism that index doesn't go beyond array items.

Comment: but shift() method remove elements from contacts array this is what I dont want

Comment: @Martin   yes it does. but you have all your data now in `data`  array. anyway you can have a copy of original array and use shift on that. any time concatenation of `data+contacts` will give you your original data back.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a global counter value, and in your function, increment it and push to the array:

```js
 

const contacts = ['Chriss:23232','Sarah:345232','Bill:893246','Mary:254366','Dianne:2434356','Amy:2356546','Andreu:23546457'];
var counter = 0;
var data = [];
function myFunc() {
    if (!(counter++ > contacts.length)) {
        data.push(contacts[counter]);
        counter++;
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        alert("No more contacts left!");
    }
}
```

```html
 

<button id="search-btn" onclick="myFunc()">Search</button>
```